# Docker PHP5.6 Call to undefined function bindtextdomain()

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, php-gettext

**Problem:**

I have a Docker compose with an nginx service and a PHP service.
When I try to open a page of my dev project, I encounter this error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function bindtextdomain() in /usr/share/nginx/html/some_project/some_path/Bootstrap.php on line 16

I saw that is a problem of a missing dependency: `php-gettext`.

**My configuration:**

In my Dockerfile, I try to install it:

```
FROM php:5.6.30-fpm
MAINTAINER DarckCrystale "xxx@xxx.xx"

# Here I try to install the php-gettext extension
# but it does not work
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php-gettext gettext

# Setup PHP configuration
ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
```

In my php.ini, I load it:

```
extension=gettext.so
```

**Other information:**

When I run in my container

```
php -i | grep extension_dir
```

I have this message displayed:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gettext.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/gettext.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

**What it seems to be to me:**

I think

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php-gettext gettext
```

does not install the `php-gettext` extension. I don't know why. I think this is a PHP Dockerized specific problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after struggle, I finally found how to install this extension in the PHP container!

**How to solve this problem?**

Use `docker-php-ext-install` instead of `apt-get install` in the Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:5.6.30-fpm
MAINTAINER DarckCrystale "xxx@xxx.xx"

# Here I install the php-gettext extension
# and it works! :D
RUN docker-php-ext-install gettext

# Setup PHP configuration
ADD php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
```

**What is the problem?**

PHP container have a specific way to install PHP extensions:

> **How to install more PHP extensions**
>
> We provide the helper scripts `docker-php-ext-configure`, `docker-php-ext-install`, and `docker-php-ext-enable` to more easily install PHP extensions.

So `php-gettext` extension installation seems to work only using provided scripts.